# High ping: router problems?

Tags: networking, router, ping

I often have extremely high pings to close locations. A `traceroute` of `www.google.com.au` revealed the following:

```
traceroute to www.google.com.au (74.125.237.191), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  BigPond.BigPond (10.0.0.138)  0.562 ms  0.752 ms  0.943 ms
 2  210.56.80.19 (210.56.80.19)  337.281 ms  337.539 ms  337.534 ms
 3  210.56.80.201 (210.56.80.201)  337.695 ms  337.687 ms  337.738 ms
 4  as15169.sydney.pipenetworks.com (218.100.2.98)  343.658 ms  351.240 ms  352.237 ms
 5  66.249.95.224 (66.249.95.224)  360.306 ms  439.944 ms  439.943 ms
 6  72.14.232.31 (72.14.232.31)  439.935 ms  432.416 ms  432.386 ms
 7  syd01s18-in-f31.1e100.net (74.125.237.191)  432.566 ms  326.633 ms  463.446 ms
```

I have a wired connection to the router and am not using the internet while doing these tests. The ping to `210.56.80.19` (the first hop outside of my home) varies between `100ms` and `1200ms`, and the distance of that IP address from my home, at least according to http://www.iplocation.net/) is about 1,000km.

Here are some line stats from the router:

```
DSL Type:   ITU-T G.992.1
Bandwidth (Up/Down) [kbps/kbps]:    384 / 8,160
Data Transferred (Sent/Received) [MB/MB]:   20.10 / 88.32
Output Power (Up/Down) [dBm]:   5.2 / 19.9
Line Attenuation (Up/Down) [dB]:    13.5 / 16.5
SN Margin (Up/Down) [dB]:   24.0 / 15.6
System Vendor ID (Local/Remote):    TMMB / ----
Chipset Vendor ID (Local/Remote):   BDCM / BDCM
```

I live approximately 80km from Sydney.

When I power-cycled my router the ping to that first hop briefly dropped to about `30ms` (for maybe about a minute or so) before climbing again into the hundreds/thousands. It is currently back down to about `30ms` as I am writing this. There seems to be a lot of fluctuation and it's impossible for me to tell whether powering off the router actually made the difference.

What else can I check to diagnose the problem before trying a new router?

Comment: I would say, simply your modem (or router) needs to be changed. I had this issue a while ago and problem was modem. And my problem was literally how you described, word for word.

Comment: [Your router line stats](http://www.kitz.co.uk/adsl/frogstats.php) might be interesting ...

Comment: @DavidPostill added. Is this what you're after? Does it tell you anything useful?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I was hoping your line stats would include error information as well, like the examples at http://www.kitz.co.uk/adsl/linestats_errors.htm

Comment: Have you contacted your isp support?

Comment: @DavidPostill yeah they told me to restart my router, which actually helped for a little while. I've bought a new router now, will see what happens and post back.